# How make BigQueryIO wait for some DoFn input

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

In ApacheBeam once you have some *PCollection input* you can do

```
input.aplly(new ParDo())
```

however BigQueryIO.read() can be applied only on the Pipeline instance, so my question is
how can I make BigQueryIO.read() wait till some other DoFn finishes or produces at least 1 output, should it be a different pipeline where I'll put BigQueryIO or can it be done within the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to make `BigQueryIO.read()` wait for some input since, actually, it creates a `PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<T>>` where `PBegin` input type says that it's supposed to be executed in the beginning of your pipeline.

I also don't see any other "read" PTransform's implemented in BigQueryIO connector that would accept any input PCollection.

So, very likely it will be easier run it as a different pipeline and use something like Apache Airflow to orchestrate them.